# How to make scroll orientation to horizontal using InfinitePlaceHolderView?

Tags: android

I'am developing an infinite place holder view, the code was fine... but the direction of loading was only in vertical direction. Here's my current dashboard view:

[image]

And my current code in `activity_dashboard.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <com.mindorks.placeholderview.InfinitePlaceHolderView
        android:id="@+id/loadMoreViewDashboard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How to make it scroll to horizontal?

You may refer my full code in Github:

https://github.com/imranhamzah/richpleasure_academy_std

Thank you for any help or comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to onCreate()

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mLoadMoreView;
LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager)layoutManager;
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
```